# Active Directory Domain Controller on Azure - Reverse setup

Tags: azure

I'm looking to setup AD for our company.  We have developed a cloud based app that needs robust permissions abilities, which AD easily can handle.  The app is bases out of Heroku which runs on AWS. I really need AD to manage logins and organizational hierarchy.

I'd like to use a cloud based service to act as the primary Domain controller and in the future, setup on-premise servers to provide local authentication to manage file/print and computer services. This is a secondary need to the authentication needs for our app.

Does anyone know if this architecture is possible? That is, a AD's DC in Azure with replicated services to other on-premise servers, at a later time?  This seems to be the reverse of most setups in Azure.  I'm ok with using other cloud services than Azure.  It just seems they have the most documentation for cloud AD setups.

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
AT

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't go for Cloud to be my primary DC, here are some guidelines which might help you:

- [Guidelines for Deploying Windows Server Active Directory on Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156090.aspx)
- [Install a new Active Directory forest in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/)

In order to fully validate your scenario, how do you think to join the Heroku computers to your domain controller? Because joining the server where your application runs will make the total sense of what you are trying to achieve.

If you just want to provide LDAP access from your application to the primary DC, and your app is not part of the Domain, then it makes **no sense** to install AD in Azure.

If you plan to just query the AD for organizational structure, I highly suggest that you take a look at the [Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/identity/) and its [Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx). this is what you need, in the case you will **not join** any computers to the domain, because Windows Azure Active Directory **is not** a Domain Controller.

**UPDATE**

Please update your question with better description of `simply to allow our Heroku based app to pull in the directory structure and login information to allow our users to authenticate to it.` - I am afraid I can't really understand the application architecture and user login flow here.

Comment: Thanks first of all for the helpful websites.

Comment: I think the initial role out will be simply to allow our Heroku based app to pull in the directory structure and login information to allow our users to authenticate to it.  So, in reality, nothing at the beginning will be authenticating against AD and only Heroku will be pulling data.  

Given this architecture, can I use this going forward to setup on-premise AD replicas to join computer's to and authenticate against locally?  Is that a completely wrong interpretation of what's possible?  I am afraid it might be if Azure is NOT a DC.

Comment: In the first part of this deployment, I am concerned most with using AD to manage permissions for our App running in Heroku.  I believe we will develop a integration of AD into Heroku using some sort of API with Azure or Heroku.  I'm pretty sure Azure can handle this function.  That is, I believe Azure's version of AD can handle creating our Organizational structure and holding our Login info.  From there, in phase 2 perhaps, what options are their to join computers to either Azure or onsite DC's?  Is this done by architecting a distributed network of DC's - possibly with different domains?